# How to create Coupon that set product price to fixed price?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to create a coupon that allows customer to buy products with fixed price.
It's something like this:

```
COUPON
|-- Category 1
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 1 => set product price to $1      
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 2 => set product price to $2
    |-- ...
|-- Category 2 
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 1 => set product price to $3
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 2 => set product price to $4
|-- Category 3
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 1 => set product price to $5
    |-- Product with X Attribute == 2 => set product price to $6
```

How to do that?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Why do you want to use a coupon and not customer group pricing? Also, what have you tried so far and where is the difficulty?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer Magento allows to set fixed amount or fixed percents per coupon, it means all applied products would be discount the same amount, but my requirements above, each product has a particular discount amount. I cannot use customer groups, because coupon should be available to all visitors and customers, means whatever who you are, coupon apply in the same way. Currently I have to create coupon code for each discount amount. I want to use only one coupon code.